# Finding Bezout coefficients

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

$$3 − 1 · (23 − 7 · 3) = −1 · 23 + 8 · 3$$

How does one get the left side to become the right side? Is it algebra? My discrete math textbook just wrote this but never explained a step by step process of how it came to be.

Comment: Just expand: $3 - 1 \cdot (23 - 7 \cdot 3) = 3 - 1 \cdot 23 + 7 \cdot 3 = -1 \cdot 23 + 8 \cdot 3$.

Comment: If you use the version of the extended Euclidean algorithm linked in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/616893/242) it will all be much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get from the left side expression to the right, treating $\color{blue}{s = 23}$ and $\color{red}{t = 3}$,
$$\begin{aligned}
\color{red}3 - 1 \cdot (\color{blue}{23} - 7 \cdot \color{red}3) &= \color{red}t - 1 \cdot (\color{blue}s - 7 \cdot \color{red}t)\\
&= \color{red}t - \color{blue}s + 7\color{red}t\\
&= 8\color{red}t - \color{blue}s\\
&= -\color{blue}s + 8\color{red}t\\
&= -1 \cdot \color{blue}{23} + 8 \cdot \color{red}3
\end{aligned}$$

This is how one obtains this type of equivalence without directly simplifying the whole expression.

Comment: check mark! Awesome answer!