# Use the euclidean algorithm to express the gcd as a linear combination

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Express the GCD(2546,122) as a linear combination of 2546 and 122

I found the gcd to be 8 and I went about writing it as a linear combination but somewhere I went wrong.. can someone find my mistake?

2=6-4(1)

2=6-[10-6(1)]

2=2(6)-10

2=2[16-10(1)]-10(1)

2=2(16)-3(10)

2=2(16)-3[106-16(6)]

2=14(16)-3(106)

2=14[122-106(1)]-3(106)]

2=14(122)-17(106)

2=14(122)-17[2546-122(20)]

2=354(122)-17(2546)

Obviously this is wrong because my linear combination doesn't equal 2. Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: $20(16)$, not $14(16)$.

Comment: @rogerl yes! Thank you!

Comment: [See here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/616893/242) for a method which is simpler and less error-prone.