# Greatest Common Divisor Euclid's Algorithm

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Find GCD of $28844$ and $-15712$. Find integers $a$ and $b$ such that $d= 28844a - 15712b$.

**My attempt**

$$\begin{align*}
28844&= -15712(-2) + (-2580)\\
-15712 &= -2580 (6) + (-232)\\
-2580 &= -232(11) + (-28)\\
-232 &= -28(8) + (-8)\\
-28 &= -8(3) + (-4)\\
-8 &= -4(2) + 0
\end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}
1 - (-2)(0) &= 1\\
0 - (-2)(1) &= 2\\
1- (-6)(2) &= 13\\
2-(11)(13) &= -141
\end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}
0 - (-2)(1) &= 2\\
1 - (-2)(2) &= 5\\
2 - (-6)(5) &= 32\\
5 - (11)(32) &= -347
\end{align*}$$
I think I do something wrong now. How to find a and b I don't know Please help.

Comment: Use [this version](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/616893/242) of the extended Euclidean algorithm. It's easier to remember, easier to compute, so less error prone.

Comment: I don't get how to do it with negative numbers.

Comment: Note $\ \gcd(a,-b) = \gcd(a,b)\ $ since $\,d\mid -b \iff d\mid b,\,$ so both $\,a,-b\,$ and $\,a,b\,$ have the same set of *common* divisors $\,d,\,$ so they have the same *greatest* common divisor. So you can restrict to nonnegative gcd arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could I have just used 28844 and 15712. Or when finding numbers such a=dq+r , I think you are suppose to choose q so that r is between 0 and |d| (not including d). But I guess you can say what you have instead of changing your work that the gcd(28844,-15712)=|-4|=4 (and just manipulate things afterwards). \ $-28-3(-8)=-4 \\ -28-3(-232-8(-28))=-4 \\ 25(-28)-3(-232)=-4 \\ 25(-2580-11(-232))-3(-232)=-4 \\ 25(-2580)-278(-232)=-4 \\ 25(-2580)-278(-15712-6(-2580))=-4 \\ 1693(-2580)-278(-15712)=-4 \\ 1693(28844+2(-15712))-278(-15712)=-4 \\ 1693(28844)+3108(-15712)=-4 \\ \text{ And finally just multiply both sides by -1. }$