# Use Euclid's algorithm to find the multiplicative inverse $11$ modulo $59$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, inverse, euclidean-algorithm

I was wondering if this answer would be correct
the multiplicative of $11$ modulo $59$ would be $5$ hence $5\cdot11 \equiv 4 \pmod{59}$.
Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

No, by definition, $ $ mod $\,59\!:\,\ n\equiv 11^{-1}\iff 11n\equiv 1.\ $ There are various way to compute modular inverses, e.g. one may use  the extended Euclidean algorithm ([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/616893/242) for an especially easy version). Alternatively we can use [Gauss's algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242)  as below

$\quad {\rm mod}\ 59\!:\ \ \dfrac{1}{11} \,\equiv\, \dfrac{5}{55}\,\equiv\, \dfrac{64}{-4}\,\equiv\, {-16}.\,\ $  Equivalently, eliminating the fractions

$\quad 11x\equiv 1\!\color{#c00}\iff\! 55x\equiv 5\!\iff\! -4x\equiv 64\!\color{#0a0}\iff\! x\equiv -16$

Above we $\color{#c00}{\rm multiplied}$ a congruence by $\,5\,$ and $\color{#0a0}{\rm cancelled}$ $\,-4\,$ from another. Doing so yields an *equivalent* congruence because such operations are *invertible,* since $\,5\,$ and $\,-4\,$ are invertible, being coprime to the modulus. By Bezout, $\,a\,$ is invertible mod $\,m\iff \gcd(a,m)= 1.\,$ If so then $\,x\equiv y\iff ax\equiv ay\,$ since we can scale the RHS by $\,a^{-1}\,$ to get the LHS (recall that congruences are preserved under scalings by the [Congruence Product Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242))

**Beware** $ $ Modular fraction arithmetic is well-defined only for fractions with denominator *coprime* to the modulus. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/921093/242) for further discussion.

Answer (score 0):

No. A multiplicative inverse $a$ has $5 \cdot a \equiv 1 \pmod{59}$ and $11$ has $5 \cdot 11 \equiv -4 \not\equiv 1\pmod{59}$. If you want to find the inverse, use the Euclidean algorithm, as you said:
\begin{align*}
  59 &= 5 \cdot 11 + 4\\
  11 &= 2 \cdot 4  + 3\\
  4  &= 1 \cdot 3  + 1\\
\end{align*}
Hence
\begin{align*}
   1 &= -1 \cdot 3 + 4\\
     &= -1 \cdot (11 - 2 \cdot 4) + 4\\
     &= -1 \cdot 11 + 3 \cdot 4\\
     &= -1 \cdot 11 + 3 \cdot (59 - 5 \cdot 11)\\
     &= -16 \cdot 11 + 3 \cdot 59
\end{align*}
Hence, $\pmod{59}$, we have
$$ 1 \equiv -16 \cdot 11 \equiv 43 \cdot 11 \pmod{59} $$
So, the multiplicative inverse is $43$.