# Simplifying a decimal number under modular arithmetic – $9.9 \pmod{13}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, floating-point

Can you please help me simplify the relation $9.9 \pmod{13}$?

It may seem like a stupid question (!) but your answers will help me very much. Thank you.

Comment: You want the answer in $\mathbb Z_{13}$?

Comment: Is there a context in which the "equation" (which is not an equation, by the way, since it does not feature the symbol "=") comes up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any fraction with denominator coprime to $\,13\,$ has a well-defined value modulo $\,13,\,$ namely $\,a/b = ab^{-1},\,$ where $\,\gcd(b,13)=1\,\Rightarrow\,b^{-1}$ exists by Bezout. [Grade school fraction arithmetic is valid](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/921093/242)  as long as we only use fractions with denominator coprime to the modulus, e.g.

$${\rm mod}\ 13\!:\,\ 9.9 \equiv \dfrac{99}{10}\equiv \dfrac{-5}{10}\equiv \dfrac{-1}{2} \equiv \dfrac{12}2\equiv 6\qquad $$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helps me. But I am a little confused about another example with your method. For example if I want to find the 4/3 (four on three) modular 17, how can I find the well-defined value modulo 17?

Comment: @Albert There are various algorithms to compute modular inverses, e.g. [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1234504/242) and its links.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing why you want to know, it's hard to give a correct answer. One answer that might be reasonable is what Python does: find a value between 0 and 12 that differs by a multiple of 13. Here are some examples.

```
PS C:\eb\python> python
Python 3.4.3 
>>> 9.9%13
9.9
>>> 21.9%13
8.899999999999999
>>>
```

The last result shows that it's using floating point arithmetic (no surprise).