# The number of roots common between the two equations is

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

> The number of roots common between the two equations

$x^3+3x^2+4x+7=0$ and $x^3+2x^2+7x+5=0$ is

$\color{green}{a.)\ 0 } \\~\\
b.)\ 1 \\~\\
c.)\ 2 \\~\\
d.)\ 3 \\~\\ $

i tried to solve both equations by subtracting then

$x^3+3x^2+4x+7-(x^3+2x^2+7x+5)=0 \\
x^2-3x+2=0 \\
x=2, \ 1$

but the answer is given as option $a.)$

I look for a short and simple way.

I have studied maths up to $12$th grade. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it isn't a mistake? It's impossible that 0 is a root for both equations as if you input $x=0$ you don't get 0.

Comment: @Malcolm It asks for the number of roots, not for the roots.

Answer (score 5):

You've found the $x$ values where the two expressions are equal.  However, at neither of these $x$-values are the expressions equal to $0$, which is what you need for roots.

Comment: i see my fault , how should i proceed now.

Comment: The numbers $1$ and $2$ are the only possible *candidates* for common root. But neither works, for clearly the first equation has no positive roots.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the *Euclidean algorithm* to the polynomials to find they're coprime, hence they can't have a common root (if they had a common root, say $\alpha$, $x-\alpha$  would be a common factor).

Comment: can u give me a link on how to use that *Euclidean algorithm* algorithm

Comment: I gave a detailed explanation with an example in the case of integers in this [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1322845/how-to-find-the-coefficients-of-bezouts-lemma/1323032#1323032).  The recurrence relations are the same for polynomials, so I hope it will be clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

Considering $$f(x)=x^3+3x^2+4x+7$$ $$g(x)=x^3+2x^2+7x+5$$ you could notice that their derivatives never cancel in the real domain. So, $f(x)=0$ has only one real root and same for $g(x)=0$. So, the maximum number of common roots is $1$.

Now, inspection :

- $f(-3)=-5$, $f(-2)=3$; so the root for $f(x)=0$ is somewhere between $-3$ and $-2$.
- $g(-1)=-1$, $g(0)=5$; so the root for $g(x)=0$ is somewhere between $-1$ and $0$.

So, no common root.

Comment: i didnt understand what u mean by this line "you could notice that their derivatives never cancel in the real domain" . i never really learned higher calculus

Comment: Since the derivative does not cancel in the real domain, the function does not go through any maximum or minimum. Since the functions are cubic polynomial with postive coefficient for $x^3$, the curves go from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$; so, they only have one real root. Is this better ? Just post. Cheers :-)

Comment: can u please show me algebraically why derivatives never cancel in real domain.

Comment: $f'(x)=3x^2+6x+4$, $g'(x)=3x^2+4x+7$. These are quadratic; compute the famous $b^2-4ac$ : it is negative for both of them. So no real root for $f'(x)=0$ and for $g'(x)=0$. Then no maximum and no minimum; the only one real root for $f(x)=0$ and for $g(x)=0$. Is this better ?