# Solve for $x, \;23+35 x ≡ 4$ (mod $ 13)$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I can simplify the equation, but I get stuck at the last step:   $\;x≡ 9^{−1} (4-10)$ (mod $13$).

My issue is that I am unsure how to compute this by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for $9^{-1} \pmod {13}$.  You can find that using the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm):

$$13 - \color{red}{9} = \color{violet}4$$
and
$$\color{red}9 - 2\times \color{violet}4=1.$$
Therefore,

$$\color{red}9 - 2 \times {(13 - 9)} = 1$$

i.e.,
$$3\times 9 -  2 \times 13  = 1.$$

Therefore $3 \times 9 \equiv 1 \pmod {13}.$

Addendum to answer comment:

$$\color{green}{9^{-1}}\times\color{orange}{(4-10)}\equiv\color{green}3\times\color{orange}{-6}\equiv\color{green}3\times\color{orange}7=21\equiv8 \pmod {13}.$$

Comment: I know how to solve the question if I am just looking for $9^{-1}$ (mod 13). But I'm not sure what to do with the (4-10). The solution indicated that x ≡ 8 (mod 13).

Comment: I added an addendum.  I could have also said $3\times -6=-18\equiv8 \pmod{13}$

Comment: Thank you for adding that bit! Really clarified my confusion

Comment: You can do $9^{-1}\pmod {13} $ but you can't do $3 (4-10)\pmod {13} $???

Comment: @torinksi Here it's easier to compute the fraction en masse - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want $1/9$ mod $13.$ There are several ways to find this, but one way is nto use that you can add $13$ to a number without changing it mod $13.$ Thus
$$\frac{1}{9}=\frac{14}{9}=\frac{27}{9}=3.$$

Answer (score 0):

$9^{-1} = 3 \pmod{13}$ as $27 = 1 \pmod{13}$ (e.g. found via the extended Euclidean algorithm).

Next, $4-10 = -6 = 7 \pmod{13}$, so your computation comes down to $7 \cdot 3 = 21 = 8 \pmod{13}$ indeed.

Just compute like you normally would going back to a representative between $0$ and $12$ whenever you need to, adding or substracting multiples of $13$.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{align}\bmod 13\!:\,\ &\dfrac{-6}9\equiv \dfrac{-2}3\equiv \dfrac{-15}3\equiv -5\ \ \\[.4em]
{\bf Or\!:}\qquad\  &\!\!\dfrac{-6}{-4}\equiv \dfrac{3}{2}\equiv\dfrac{16}{2}\equiv 8\\[.4em]
{\bf Or\!:}\qquad\  &\!\!\dfrac{-6}{-4}\equiv \dfrac{-18}{-12}\equiv\dfrac{-5}{1}
\end{align}\ $

The prior used [Gauss's algorithm.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242)  Generally the [extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/616893/242), or its [fractional form](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2053174/242) is efficient whether for man or machine. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2368266/242) for more examples.

**Beware** $\ $ Modular fraction arithmetic is well-defined only for fractions with denominator *coprime* to the modulus. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/921093/242) for further discussion.

Answer (score -1):

We have 23 +35x =4(mod13)
It gives 35x =-19 =7(mod13)
It further gives 9x =7(mod13)
Implies 90x=70 (mod13) gives -x=5(mod13) implies x=8(mod13)