# Can someone please help me out with this modular arithmetic problem?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I've been trying to see how to calculate this math problem: 10+9a{ mod } 23 =14.I know that a=3, but I don't know the steps to apply to these digits to get 'a' if I were to calculate it. 10+9*3{ mod }23=14. I'm just looking for the steps on how to find 'a'. If I were asked to calculate it. Thanks so much in advance. And Please I would understand more if you could  implement the answer mathematically like the way it's in the question above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$10+9a\equiv14\bmod23\implies9a\equiv4\bmod23\implies9a\equiv27\bmod23\implies a\equiv3\bmod23.$

Comment: J. W. Tanner thanks bro but your answer is incorrect..... 27 mod 23 is 4...... Because 9*4=36 not 27.... The only way this solution could be applied is when 4 is three which means 9*3 would be equal to 27. Thanks so much bro

Comment: My answer is correct.  I agree that $27$ mod $23$ is $4$; that's why I wrote $9a\equiv4\bmod23\implies 9a\equiv27\bmod23$.  And I agree that $9\times4=36$ not $27$; that's why I wrote $9a\equiv27\bmod23\implies a\equiv3$ (not $4$) $\bmod 23$

Comment: Oh.... Smart one bro....  You divided 27 by 9 to get 3 mod 23. Thanks a lot bro

Comment: Bro did you add the mod 23 to 4 to get 27..?

Comment: Yes, $4\equiv4+0\equiv4+23\equiv27\bmod23$

Comment: Makes sense....  But does your solution apply to this question: 8=17*a mod 23

Comment: $17a\equiv8\equiv-15\equiv-38\equiv-61\equiv-84\equiv-107\equiv-130\equiv-153\bmod23$ so $a\equiv-9\equiv14\bmod23$

Comment: Your answer is confusing.... Please could you break it down for me....  I'm confused especially on the part where the number adds/multiplies up....  Thanks in advance

Comment: I just keep adding or subtracting the modulus, which doesn't change the residue class, until I find a representative where I can divide both sides to solve for $a$

Comment: Oh I now see....  It has a common additive value... Could you break down the part when you divided both sides to get 14.

Comment: We have $17a\equiv-153\bmod23$.  Since $17$ is relatively prime to $23$, we can divide both sides by $17$ to get $a\equiv-9\bmod23$.  Then I just added $0\equiv23$ to get $a\equiv-9+23=14\bmod23$

Comment: Tanner Nice one..... i'm surprised on how you knew that 153 was the right number to tally with 17..... would that be a problem if the number was somewhat larger? Like Ten digits large

Comment: If the numbers were much larger, I would use the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm)

Comment: How does that work? Is it like an extended version of this answer.... Please  I would love an example if you don't mind

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3127016/solve-for-x-2335-x-%e2%89%a1-4-mod-13)

Comment: I didn't see the extended Euclidean algorithm..... I did see your answer though and i couldn't understand yours either....... i'm new to this algorithm

Answer (score 1):

It implies $9a \pmod{23}=4$ and as $gcd(9,23)=1$ it guarantees the existence of one $a$ satisfying this (To see why, suppose not, and $9a=9b \pmod{23}$ for some distinct $a,b$ such that $|a-b|<23$. As $gcd(9,23)=1$ you can cancel the $9$ both sides to obtain $|a-b| = 0 \pmod {23}$ which is false as $|a-b|<23$, thus one should have $a=b$). Now use brute force. (I am not sure if other methods exist, which is unlikely as they rely on computation, it is fine if you show the existence of such $a$, then you obtain infinitely many $a$)

Comment: @Andrew bro I don't understand your calculations..... What happened to the mod?

Comment: $a=b\pmod n$ is actually another way to write $n | a-b$, so...

Comment: Please could you implement the answer mathematically like the way it's in the question above

Comment: Ok, i will edit it. Is it fine now?