# Linear Combinations and Euclidean Algorithm question

Tags: euclidean-algorithm

This is the working to find the gcd using the Euclidean algorithm
$$\begin{align}1820 &= 7(231) + 203 & (a) \\
231 &= 1(203) + 28 &(b)\\
203 &= 7(28) + 7 &(c)\\
28 &= 4(7)+0 &(d)\\
\end{align}$$

The last non-zero remainder is 7, so gcd(1820, 231) = 7.

And then to find linear combination m and n:

$$\begin{align}
7 &= 203 − 7(28) &\mathrm{from}\ (c) \\
  &= 203 − 7(231 − 203) &\mathrm{from}\ (b) \\
  &= (−7)(231) + 8(203) \\
  &= (−7)(231) + 8(1820 − 7(231)) &\mathrm{from}\ (a)\\
  &= 8(1820) + (−63)(231)\\
\end{align}
$$

However I'm confused at the linear combination line where it has  `= (−7)(231) + 8(203)`. Where did the 8 come from in this line? There was no 8 in the previous line.

Comment: 203-7(231-203) = 203-7*231+7*203 = (-7)*231+8*203 might be what you're looking for? (Also, in a post where you're using expressions like 8(203) to denote multiplication, using (2), (3), etc. for line markers is downright cruel...)

Comment: The $8$ comes from $(1+7)$ [times $203$]

Comment: The previous line was $7 = 203 - 7(231 - 203)$.  Expand the out.  $203 - 7(231-203) = 203 - 7*231 + 7*203 = 203 + 7*203 - 7*231 = 203(1 + 7) - 7*231 = 203*8 - 7*231$.  That's where it came from.

Comment: "Where did the 8 come from in this line? There was no 8 in the previous line."  No... but there was as $203 - 7(-203)$ in the previous line :)

Comment: The reason you're having difficulty is because this is an *extremely poor* method to extend the Euclidean algorithm. Instead you should use [this method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/616893/242) which is much simpler so much less error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

The extended Euclidean algorithm is more easily done this way, in tabular form:

$$\begin{matrix} 1820 & 1 & 0 & -\\
231 & 0 & 1 & 7 \\
203 & 1 & -7 & 1 \\
28 & -1 & 8 & 7 \\
7 & 8 & -63 & 4 \\
0 & (-33) & (260) & - \\
\end{matrix}$$

where the first column are the remainders you computed, the final column the quotients, and the two in the middle are the coefficients of $1820$ and $231$ respectively.

To compute 203 we do $1820 - 7 \times 231$ so the coefficients are 
found using the same relation on the previous rows: a row with $1$ and $0$ (for $1820$) minus 7 times the row with $0$ and $1$, giving $1$ (for $1 - 7 \times 0$)
and $-7$ (for $0 - 7 \times 1$) hence the third row. 
203 goes once into 231 so we have $0\ 1$ minus $1$ times $0 \ -7$ giving $-1 \ 8$.

We go on that way (e.g. $-63 = -7 - 7 \times 8$ etc.) until we reach $0$ on the left (no need to do those coefficients; I put them between braces) and then the row before it has the gcd and its coefficient combination:

$$7 = 8 \times 1820 + (-63) \times 231$$

This avoids the error-prone back-substitutions and is easy to program.