# Euclid's algorithm tutorial

Tags: euclidean-algorithm

I am learning about the Euclidean algorithm, and here is an image with the workings.

[image]

I got stuck towards the end.

My friend tried to help me, saying just put the three together. I understand that on the second line the equation is rearranged, however I do not understand how we got to the third line:

```
3 - 1*26 + 8*3 
= 3 + 8*3 - 1*26 
= (1+8)*3 - 1*26
```

In the image, I can see that `v = 9` because of the `3v` where `9 * 3`. However, I do not understand why `w = -1` when on the last line `9*3 = 1+1 * 26` has no negative numbers?

Comment: $9\cdot 3=1+1\cdot 26$ is equivalent to $9\cdot 3 - 1\cdot 26 = 1$, hence the $-1$.

Comment: There is an *extended Euclidean algorithm* that makes the calculation of Bézout's coefficients automatic (and which less error-prone).

Comment: The last line is *not* in the form $3v + 26w = 1$.  It is int the form $3m= 1 + 26n$ i.e. $3\cdot 9 = 1 + 1\cdot 26$.  To get it in the form $3v + 26w = 1$ we must subtract $1\cdot 26$ from each side so get $3\cdot 9 - 1\cdot 26 = 1$.  *NOW* it is in the form of $3v + 26w = 1$.  .... (Note: If $3v+26w =1$ and $3,26 >1$ we *know* from the get go that one of the numbers will *have* to be negative.  Otherwise you'd get a number much bigger than $1$)

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/616893/242) for a much simpler and much less error- prone version of the extended Euclidean algorithm. Once you learn this *forward* method you'll never use the cumbersome  *backward* method again

Answer (score 1):

The last line is *not* in the form $3v + 26w = 1$.

So you aren't done yet.

To get $3\cdot 9 = 1 + 1\cdot 26$ to the form $3w +26v = 1$ where the $3w$ and $26v$ are both on the LEFT HAND SIDE and the $1$ is all by itself on the RIGHT HAND SIDE, we will have to subtract $26\cdot 1$ from both side.

> $3\cdot 9 = 1 + 1\cdot 26$
> $3\cdot 9 - 1\cdot 26 = 1 $

*NOW* it is in the form of $3v + 26w = 1$.  ...

(Note: If $3v+26w =1$ and $3,26 >1$ we *know* from the get-go that one of the numbers will *have* to be negative.  Otherwise you'd get a number much bigger than $1$)

.....

Actually, it *is* funny how (at least to me) the equation

> $9 w + 26v = 1$

looks a feels *very* different to me than

> $9 w = 1 + 26b$

But the are completely equivalent.

Comment: I will be honest that I did not understand. Could you perhaps walk me through step by step from the beginning, rather than me trying to fit this into potentially the wrong place? Sorry to be a pain.

Comment: What's to not understand?  If you want to find numbers $w,v$ so that $3v + 26w = 1$ then $v=9$ and $w=-1$ are such a pair of numbers because $3\cdot 9 + 26\cdot (-1) = 27-26 = 1$.  We know that $9, -1$ is such a pair becaue $3\times 9 = 1 + 26\cdot 1$ so that means $3\times 9 - 26\cdot 1 = 1$.