# number theory Diophantine equation real world example.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

A man paid $11.37$ for $39$ cent and $69$ cent pens. We wish to solve for

$$39x+69y=1137$$

However, since $(39,69)=3 \mid 1137$ this reduces down to

$$13x+23y=379 \space \space \space (*)$$

Then the text reads: Using the Euclidean algorithm on $13$ and $23$ and solving the equations backwards gives

$$13(-7)+23(4)=1$$

I wanna know how they got $-7$ and $4$ so quickly and why this implies $-7,4$ are solutions to $(*)$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It’s a guess. Pure Hit and Trial. As for the second question, they are not solutions; 13(-7)+23(4)=1 implies 13(-7*379)+23(4*379)=379, so x=-7*379 and y=4*379 are solutions to (*).

Comment: No, it is not a guess. It is the Euclidean algorithm, which is very quick. It gives $13\cdot(-7)+23\cdot 4=1$. Now multiply the equation by $379$. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20717/how-to-find-solutions-of-linear-diophantine-ax-by-c), for example.

Comment: Did the text say “quickly?” It is obviously deleting steps, and indicating how to fill them in.

Comment: In any event, the word “quickly” does not have a technical meaning. The Euclidean algorithm is $$23=13\cdot 1+10\\13=10\cdot 1+3\\10=3\cdot 3+1\\3=1\cdot 3+0.$$ The reversing is another four steps to get the answer. So it depends on what is meant by “quickly.”

Comment: what is meant by reversing @ThomasAndrews

Comment: $13x\!+\!23y = 379\iff \bmod 13\!:\ {-}3y\equiv 2\equiv 15\!\iff\! y\equiv -5\equiv 8,\,$ so $\, x = (379\!-\!8(23))/13 = 15.\ $ As explained in the linked dupe, as above, solving that linear diophantine equation is equivalent to solving a linear congruence, for which there are many known methods (follow the links there). There is no need to first solve the case with RHS $= 1.\ $ Alternatively you can apply the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/616893/242).

Comment: For the book's way, as above: $\bmod 13\!:\ {-}3y\equiv 1\equiv -12\iff y\equiv 4,\,$ so $\,x = (1-4(23))/12 = -7.\ $ It's $\:\!< 10$ seconds of mental arithmetic either way (but done the book's way you still need to scale by $379$, which is more work).

Comment: From the Euclidean algorithm, you get $$\begin{align}1&=10+3\cdot (-3)\\1&=10+(13+10\cdot(-1))(-3)\\&=10\cdot4+13\cdot(-3)\\1&=(23\cdot1+13\cdot (-1))\cdot4+13\cdot(-3)\\&=23\cdot4+13\cdot(-7) \end{align} $$ This sort of reverses the Euclidean algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they used the Euclidean Algorithm to solve for $x=-7, y=4$ although they did not show it. here it is: First, $23=1\cdot 13+1\cdot 10, 13=1\cdot 10+1\cdot3, 10=3\cdot 3+1\cdot 1$, so we have:
\begin{align}
1&= 10-3\cdot 3 \\
&= 10-3\cdot(13-1\cdot 10) \\
&= 4\cdot 10-3\cdot 13 \\
&= 4(23-1\cdot 13)-3\cdot 13 \\
&= 4\cdot 23-7\cdot 13.
\end{align}

Since this pair is a solution to $13x+23y=1$, then multiplying both sides of the equation by $379$ gives you that the pair $x=-7\cdot 379, y=4\cdot379$ is a solution to $(*)$. Finally, to find a valid solution to your original problem, notice that $13\cdot23 -23\cdot 13 = 0$. So, if we add $23$ to $x$ and subtract $13$ from $y$ we will have another valid solution. To see this explicitly, $$(13\cdot23 -23\cdot 13) + 379(13\cdot-7+23\cdot4)= 0 + 379(13\cdot-7+23\cdot4)= 379\cdot 1= 379.$$
So we can add $c$ multiples of $23$ to $x$ and subtract multiples of $13$ from $y$ to get soltuions where both $x$ and $y$ are positive.

Comment: could you show me how they used the Euclidean algorithm to solve for $-7$ and $4$??

Comment: @HossienSahebjame to make sure you aren't just using this site to get solutions to hw problems, i think it is best if you figure this part out on your own. there are thousands of examples of the euclidean algorithm on the internet and therefore, you can simply adapt it to solve for solutions to the equation $13x+23y=1$. this answer was written to give you intuition for the implications of the solution to the equation given by the algorithm.

Comment: no I am teaching a course to computer engineers which requires some number theory and I am preparing lecture notes. I need to make sure I understand it first before teaching it. I tried rewriting the equations backwards but I don't get how they got -7 and 4.

Comment: @HossienSahebjame ill take your word for it.

Comment: @Hossien If you insist on doing it the long way using the extended Euclidean algorithm as above, then you should *always* teach it in [said **forward** form](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/616893/242), since the above backward substitution form is *notoriously error prone* and is far less intuitive. You can find many worked examples (including errors!) in the "linked" posts [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242)

Comment: @amathguy Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).