# discrete mathematics, Euclidean algorithm

Tags: discrete-mathematics, euclidean-algorithm

I'm having troubles to find the coefficients: 1357 + 49 = 1 = (1357,49).
I started solving the equations by the Euclidean algorithm, but I can't replace them all. Can someone help me?

[image]

From then on I couldn't do it anymore.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  You should show your attempt

Comment: Show at least the beginning of the Euclidean Algorithm you did, and I will complete that...The resulting numbers are not that low.

Comment: Ok, I added an image. @DonAntonio

Comment: Thank you, ok, I added an image @J.W.Tanner

Comment: You should write the numbers in the post to avoid down-votes and votes to close. A cursory glance at the work in your link shows that this is a perfectly acceptable question but that can't be seen from what you actually posted.

Comment: On the second-to-last equation, did you mean $1=4\cdot34-\color{red}9\cdot15$?

Comment: As @J.W.Tanner points out, you just made an arithmetic mistake on the penultimate line.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/616881/extended-euclidean-algorithm-backward-vs-forward)

Comment: It's true, I made a mistake

Comment: You can also verify yourself that equality no longer holds since which line.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: **Duplicate** of  [Extended Euclidean Algorithm: backward and forward form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/616881/extended-euclidean-algorithm-backward-and-forward-form)

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{cases}
1357=49\cdot27+34\\{}\\
49=34\cdot1+15\\{}\\
34=15\cdot2+4\\{}\\
15=4\cdot3+3\\{}\\
4=3\cdot1+1\\{}\\
3=1\cdot3+0\;\text{(check case)}\end{cases}$$

And now read from bottom to top:

$$1=4-3=4-(15-4\cdot3)=4\cdot4-15=4(34-15\cdot2)-15=4\cdot34-9\cdot15=$$

$$=4\cdot34-9(49-34)=13\cdot34-9\cdot49=13(1357-49\cdot27)-9\cdot49$$

$$=13\cdot1357-360\cdot49$$

Comment: Thank you so much!