# How does the reduction work in backwards substitution in Bézout's identity?

Tags: euclidean-algorithm

I'm a bit stuck on one part of Bézout's identity when used with Euclid's algorithm.

The specific part of the equation I can't see is;

```
               3=27-4*(60-2*27)
```

Which reduces to

3=9*27-4*60

(How and why should we know to reduce the equation in this format?)

Then we backward substitute again to say

```
               3=9*(207-3*60)-4*60
```

Which reduces to

3=9x207-31*60

(Again, how and why do we reduce the equation in this manner?)

This is to satisfy the equation av+bw=d.

Many thanks!

Comment: Huh? You mean $9\times 27 - 4\times 60$? You’re doing back substitution carefully to get $3=ma+nb$, where $a$ and $b$ are the integers you started with. This is explained clearly in every elementary number theory and algebra text.

Comment: Please read [the Note](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/616893/242) in an answer in the dupe for the key idea behind back-substitution. But you should **stop doing it backwards** and instead propagate **forward** the linear combinations, since that direction is much simpler and far less error-prone - as explained there. $\ \ $