# There exists more than one set of numbers $(m,n)$ so that $132m+34n=\gcd(132,34)$?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Does there exists more than one set of numbers $(m,n)$ so that $132m+34n=\gcd(132,34)$?

I was comparing to, and thinking about how and why euclids algorithm solves for one set.

How might one find the other sets?

Comment: When you say $m132$ do you mean $m\cdot132$ or the digit $m$ followed by $132$, so, say, $m=2$ gives $2132$?

Comment: Are you asking how to find all solutions once you have found one solution?

Comment: i meant m⋅132. 
I'm asking, how you can find any solution other than the one via the extended euclidean algorithm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

suppose you have found $m,n$ that satisfy the equality.

notice that the other solutions can be found via

$$\left(m+k\frac{34}{\gcd(132,34)}\right)132+\left( n-k\frac{132}{\gcd(132,34)}\right)34= \gcd(132,34)$$

Edit:

It is clear that solutions are those forms are indeed a solution. However, I have not justified I have covered all the solutions.

suppose $$132m+34n=132m'+34n'$$
$$34(n-n')=132(m'-m)$$
$$\frac{34}{\gcd(132,34)}(n-n')=\frac{132}{\gcd(132,34)}(m'-m)$$

Since $\frac{34}{\gcd(132,34)}$ and $\frac{132}{\gcd(132,34)}$ are both coprime,

$$\exists k \in \mathbb{Z}, m'-m=\frac{34}{\gcd(132,34)}k$$
As a result, we also have

$$n-n'=\frac{132}{\gcd(132,34)}k$$

Hence all the solutions satisfy

$$m'=m+\frac{34}{\gcd(132,34)}k, n'=n-k\frac{132}{\gcd(34,132)}$$

Comment: Perhaps it is helpful to the reader to remark why these are all the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ Since $\,ax+by\,$ is *linear* in $\,x,y,\,$ the [general solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/182469/242) of $\ ax+by=c\ $ is the sum of any particular solution $\,(x_0,y_0)\,$ plus the general solution solution of the associated homogeneous equation $\,ax+by = 0,\,$ which is $\,(x,y)= n(-\bar b,\bar a),\,$ where $\,\bar a/\bar b\,$ is the lowest terms rep of $\,a/b,\,$ i.e. where $\,\bar a,\bar b\,$ are coprime. Summing these two components gives the general solution

$$\,(x,y)\, =\, (x_0,y_0)+n(-\bar b,\bar a)\, =\, (x_0-n\bar b,\,y_0 + n\bar a)$$