# Find the value of $x,y$ for the equation $12x+5y=7$ using number theory .

Tags: elementary-number-theory, linear-diophantine-equations

I tried the solution using other ways like:

$12x+5y=7$

$12x=7-5y$

$x=7-5y/12$

putting the value of $x$

$12(7-5y/12)+5y=7$

both $12$ will cancel out

$7-5y+5y=7$
here comes the problem please help me ?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  You'll get a lot more help if your questions are easy to read.

Comment: Do $x,y$ need to be integers?

Comment: $12\times1+5\times(-1)=7$

Comment: He lost the $12$ in the 4th line as well, so he forgot it twice and got the right answer in the end.

Comment: $x=\left(\dfrac{7-5y}{12}\right)$

Comment: Anyways you are using a circular argument. Since you are finding $x$ in terms of $y$ and substituting back in the equation will give you $0=0$.

Answer (score 1):

> You can use the theorem of diophantine equations that if a equation
>
> $ax+by=c$
>
> is given and $a\neq0$, $b\neq0$, then let $g=gcd(a,b)$. If $g \nmid c$ then no solutions. If $g \mid c$, then infinitely many solutions. If the pair $(x_1,y_1)$ is a solution, then all other solutions are $x=x_1+kb/g$, $y=y_1-ka/g$ where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

So here $a=12$, $b=5$, $g=1$, $c=7$. $g \mid c$ and $(1,-1)$ is one solution.

Using above theorem

$x=1+5k$

$y=-1-12k$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: i.e. $(x,y) = (x_1,y_1) + k\,(b,-a)/g,\,$ i.e. general solution = [particular + homongeneous solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/182469/242)

Comment: @BillDubuque Exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $7 = 12-5\implies 12(-x+1) = 5(y+1)$, and since $\text{gcd}(5,12) = 1$, we have: $-x+1 = 5k, y+1 = 12k\implies x = -5k+1, y = 12k-1, k \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: sir the question is 12x + 5y=7, there is plus sign not minus

Comment: @NamanBansal: Please double check your algebra since it is true.

Comment: it's given in the book sir. and answer should be an integer