# Structure of linear Diophantine system

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, systems-of-equations, algebraic-number-theory, linear-diophantine-equations

I am learning about the linear system of Diophantine equations. I have noticed that the solution structure of the Diophantine equation is quite similar to the general system of linear equations. It is $S=x_0+F$, where $x_0$ is a partial solution and $F$ is the solution set of the corresponding homogeneous Diophantine linear system, $F$ is the submodule of $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Z^n}$.
But in the general system of equations, $F$ is a subspace of the vector space $K^n$. 
So, is the proof for the root structure theorem of the linear system of the Diophantine equations similar to the general system of equations? If it is different, can someone give me a tutorial to proof, please?

My proof for the structure of the solution set of a general linear equation system:

**Theorem:** If the general system of linear equations
$\left\{\begin{array}\
a_{11}x_1+\cdot+a_{1n}x_n=b_1\\
\vdots\\
a_{m1}x_1+\cdots+a_{mn}x_n=b_m
\end{array}\right. (*)
$
has a solution, then the solution set $S$ has the form
$$S=x_0+F,$$
where $x_0$ is a partial solution of $(*)$ and $F$ is the solution set of the corresponding homogeneous system of linear equations, $F$ is a subspace of $K^n$.

*Proof:*
The system $(*)$ can be written as $f(x)=b$. We have $f(x_0)=b$ and $F=Ker(f)$. Suppose that $x\in K^n$ is any solution of $(*)$, then $f(x)=b$. This implies $f(x-x_0)=0$. Hence $x-x_0\in Ker(f)=F$. Thus $x\in x_0+F$. Conversely, if $x=x_0+w$, for $w\in F$, then
$$f(x)=f(x_0+w)=f(x_0)+f(w)=b+0=b.$$
Therefore $x$ is a solution of $(*)$. Hence $S=x_0+F$.

Comment: All you have to do is show that the difference between two solutions is a solution to the homogeneous system, no?

Comment: The well-known form of the general solution (e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/182469/242)) holds for any *linear* system, something that will be abstracted when one studies linear algebra, modules, affine spaces, etc, but can still be comprehended easily at more elementary levels in concrete cases such as here.